# Does PyObject_CallObject steal reference to args? (do I need to free the memory?)

Tags: python, c

The documentation for Python, is again just as the language, beautiful but lacking and sort of inefficient :) - https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_CallObject

I am calling `PyObject_CallObject` in my C code, and wonder if args that I created (`PyObject*`) need to be freed after the call, or if they are consumed by Python.

That means, in some cases, Python consumes the variable, meaning it will call `Py_DECREF` for you, and subsequential calls of `Py_DECREF` may have undocumented results.

In case it doesn't, I should call Py_DECREF otherwise it would leak. So question is: do I need to free the memory here or I don't? I would expect args to be consumed by call, but documentation doesn't say anything about it.

Comment: Without any documentation, I would create a loop and check for memory leaks.

Comment: Have you read the general information on reference-counting here? https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/intro.html#reference-count-details  In particular, read the bit about "stealing references".

Comment: @MarkDickinson yes which is why I am asking here. The page you linked say ```Conversely, when a calling function passes in a reference to an object, there are two possibilities: the function steals a reference to the object, or it does not. Stealing a reference means that when you pass a reference to a function, that function assumes that it now owns that reference, and you are not responsible for it any longer.``` I need to know if the function I used steals a reference or not. If it does, I don't need to care, if it doesn't I need to.

Comment: No, `PyObject_CallObject` doesn't steal a reference. As the docs say, very few functions do, and those that do are explicitly documented as such.

Comment: In general, the caller still owns the reference and must decrement it. Callables that steal a reference should document that they do. So for instance [PyTuple_SetItem](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/tuple.html#c.PyTuple_SetItem) notes that it steals a reference. It is a bit confusing and perhaps risky but I guess if 99% of the functions act one way, its a bit tedious to keep mentioning.

Comment: @Petr: For these sorts of questions, it's also frequently helpful to look at Python's own source. There are plenty of occurrences of `PyObject_CallObject` in the `Modules` subdirectory of the source tree. Note that most of those occurrences *don't* do a `Py_DECREF` on the `PyObject_CallObject` arguments, but that's usually because they're passing references that they don't own in the first place (e.g., because those references were in turn borrowed from the caller of the function that calls `PyObject_CallObject`).